# C++ doesn't save the changes by other method

Tags: c++, linked-list, operator-overloading

I'm trying to implement a linked list class in C++ and I got problem. I have the += operator who adds new node.

the linked list class interface:

```
template <typename Type>

class LinkedList {
public:
    LinkedList<Type>* head;
//  linked list stracture
    Type data;
    LinkedList<Type>* next;
//  others ....
    size_t length;
public:
    LinkedList();
    ~LinkedList();
    void initializeHead(LinkedList<Type>* headPtr);
    size_t size() const;
    LinkedList& operator+=(const Type& add);
    void operator-=(const Type& remove);
    LinkedList<Type>& operator[] (const size_t index) const;
    bool operator== (const LinkedList<Type> &versus) const;
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& out,LinkedList& obj);
};
```

and here i have the += overload implement:

```
template <typename Type> LinkedList<Type>& LinkedList<Type>::operator +=(const Type& add) {
    // head ptr - :)
    LinkedList<Type>* p = head->next;
    // go to the end
    while(p) p = p->next;
    // now on end - create new..!!!
    try {
        p = new LinkedList<Type>;
    } catch (bad_alloc& e) {
        cout << "There\'s an allocation error....";
    } catch (...) {
        cout << "An unknown error.." << endl;
    }// fill and done
    p->data = add;
    p->next = NULL;
    // increment length .........
    ++head->length;
    // done ............
    return *p;
}
```

Additionally , I have "array" access overload method:

```
template <typename Type> LinkedList<Type>& LinkedList<Type>::operator [](const size_t index) const {
    if(index < 0 || index >= length) // invaild argument
        throw  exception();
    // continue
    LinkedList<Type>* p = head;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < index; ++i) p = p->next; // we are at what we want
    return *p;
}
```

All works correctly - I checked on the dibugger,

the problem is - += doesn't save the new node in "head->next", for some reason, after finish += method, head->next equal to null.

Do someone know why the new allocation don't link to head->next?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: If you try to implement as stack it will be much simpler.

Comment: Linked lists are not any better than vectors. They are actually slower, and they do not support random access. At least implement such LL, that has constant time insertion, not O(n).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after  `while(p) p = p->next;` p is NULL

and next you do `p = new LinkedList<Type>;` but you don't link the p into the head.

Comment: Thanks, its better, it saves it new node - but It's seems like theres no NULL at the end of the list.. do you know why?

Comment: p->data = data; p->next = NULL; I think last node of the list should point to this new node to get the your expected results(NULL at end).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
// go to the end
while(p) p = p->next;
```

You need:

```
head->next = p;
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers say, you go beyond the list when you try to add. Try something like this:

```
template <typename Type> LinkedList<Type>& LinkedList<Type>::operator +=(const Type& add)
{
    LinkedList<Type> *last;

    // Find the last node in the list
    for (last = head; last != 0 && last->next != 0; last = last->next)
    {
    }

    // `last` now points to the last node in the list, or is zero
    // If zero (i.e. NULL) then list is empty

    if (last == 0)
    {
        head = new LinkedList<Type>;
        head->next = 0;
        head->data = add;
        head->length = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        last->next = new LinkedList<Type>;
        last->next->next = 0;
        last->next->data = add;
    }

    // We can safely use `head` as we are sure it won't be zero
    head->length++;

    // Return the added node
    return (last != 0 ? *last->next : *head);
}
```

Comment: Mm.. Ok, I try to fix by myself the `delete` problem. Thank you all very much!

Comment: @nimrod Be sure that the constructor zeroes the `head` member variable. Preferably the other variables as well, then you don't have to zero them out in the function I posted.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use temporary variable to store last node and then the last node will point to new node.

This is sample code. You need to take care of some situations like adding first node etc.

```
LinkedList<Type>* temp = NULL;
while(p) 
{
  temp = p;
  p = p->next;   
}  

try 
{             
  p = new LinkedList<Type>;         
  temp->next = p;
}
```